# Magento 2 - Custom Payment Module Order Email

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, order-email

I have a custom payment module and I can see the method in the frontend and in the order form in the admin.  Where I don't see it is in the order email.  What do I need to do to get it there?

Comment: Please confirm, it is showing in the admin order view page?

Comment: Hi Nits!  Yes, I see the information in the admin order view page.  I thought I would then also see it in the email.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be an issue with your custom payment method extension or you miss a small thing. So I would suggest, try to review the below links and compare your code with it.

> https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-payment-method/
>
> https://www.classyllama.com/blog/how-to-create-payment-method-magento-2

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks!  I will check and report back.

Comment: I don't see anything referencing the order email.  Is there something specific I am looking for?

Comment: @stanhook if your extension has follow the steps which mentioned in the link then it will work and reflect properly in the email. Please review your code and confirm.